# How to create event listener that checks style of the div element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this div declared in my html page :

```
<div class="ol-unselectable ol-layers" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;">
</div>
```

At some point to the style in div element above display changed to none:

```
<div class="ol-unselectable ol-layers" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0; display: none;">
</div>
```

When to the div element added display: none; I need to fire this row:

```
alert("not displayed");
```

for this purpose, I need to create a listener that will fire alert when display changed to none.

My question is how can I make an event listener that listens is div style has `display: none` attribute?

Comment: How is `display` being changed to `none`?

Comment: @AJFerron some third party, library do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the change in CSS is done with JavaScript, you can use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect the change. It will call the given function every time DOM changes occur to the target element.

```js
const target = document.querySelector('.ol-unselectable');

const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    for(let {type, target} of mutations) {
        if (type === 'attributes' && target.style.display === 'none')
            alert("not displayed")
    }
})

observer.observe(target, {attributes: true})

target.addEventListener('click', () => target.style.display='none')
```

```css
.ol-unselectable {
  background: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ol-unselectable ol-layers" style="position: absolute; width: 50%; height: 50%; z-index: 0;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [MutationObserver.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) The following includes comments and base code from MDN docs

```js
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
const targetNode = document.getElementById('test');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = {attributes: true};

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
  // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
  for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
    const {type, attributeName } = mutation;
    if (type === 'attributes' && attributeName === 'style' && targetNode.style.display === 'none') {

      console.log('Style is none');
    }
  }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
   const {style} = targetNode;
   style.display = style.display === 'none' ?'block':'none'

})
```

```html
<button>
Toggle content
</button>

<div id="test">Content</div>
```